# Failed review audit on answer, where question itself should have been closed

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16620664) to review. Turns out it was an audit. This was the result.

[image: screenshot of audit result]

My problem with this is that the answer was originally closed as 'very low quality'. IMHO, that decision was **completely wrong**. Let's review the facts

- The answer was posted by the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6900040/devashish-khattar), who ought to know something about answering their own question
- The answer explained that the cause of the original problem was that a file had been mistakenly placed in the wrong folder.

It may have been a short answer, but it certainly appears to answer the original question, and it was certainly posted by someone qualified to answer, and it is very likely indeed that it was absolutely the '**right**' answer.

As it stands at the time of my asking this question, [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199918/http-404-resource-not-found-when-project-run-on-server-on-spring-tool-suite/44544356#44544356) has no (visible) answers.

In my opinion **the original question should have been closed** once the OP had posted his answer explaining that, in effect, the question was as a result of

> a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error

which is perfectly a valid close reason.

Instead, we have what we now know to be a question of dubious value that

> was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers

(from that same close reason), but we're not actually letting them in on the secret that it *was* solved, nor *how* it was solved. And it's still there inviting somebody to waste their time answering it, and potentially polluting search results and misleading site visitors.

Am I correct in my reasoning or am I missing something?

Comment: The first comment on that answer says, *Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.* Unfortunately, I keep seeing that on answers from the OP in that queue. I don't know if they honestly can't tell that the OP is posting an actual answer or what. (I don't know why the other commentor didn't feel it was an answer either.)

Comment: Wow.  That was a bad audit.  Not sure what those reviewers were thinking.  Voting to undelete the Answer and close voting the question as a typo.

Comment: Maybe the audit system should deliberately pick a certain percentage of good questions/answers that are very short, in order to train reviewers that short doesn't mean bad.

Comment: Really an edge case this one I would say, but indeed the good call would, IMO to leave the answer as is and to close the question as typo. Now since answer and question are from the same person, then... Maybe he should have not posted the answer and delete or ask a close on its own question. So that makes both the answer and the question good calls for a close vote

Comment: Answers cannot be closed. Did you mean flagged?